# Kotlin type mismatch compile error: Require Success<T>, Found MyError

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am encountering an issue that the following code can't be compiled in kotlin.

```
// StateModel.kt
sealed class StateModel
class Loading : StateModel()
data class Success<T: Any>(val data: T) : StateModel()
data class MyError(val message: String) : StateModel()

// StateModelTransformer.kt
class StateModelTransformer<T: Any> : FlowableTransformer<T, StateModel> {

  override fun apply(upstream: Flowable<T>): Publisher<StateModel> {
    return upstream
      .map { data -> Success(data) }
      .onErrorReturn { error ->
        MyError(error.message)  // compile error, Type mismatch, Require Success<T>, Found MyError
      }
      .startWith(Loading()) // compile error, none of the following function can be called with the arguments supplied
  }

}
```

I have no idea why the `onErrorReturn` says requiring a `Success<T>` type but a `StateModel` type.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the relevant declarations in `Flowable`, for reference. Let's ignore `onErrorReturn`; it's not relevant to the problem here.

```java
public Flowable<T> {
    public <R> Flowable<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
    public Flowable<T> startWith(T value);
}
```

These are the types Kotlin infers.

```kotlin
val upstream: Flowable<T>
val mapper:   (T) -> Success<T>    = { data -> Success(data) }
val map:      ((T) -> Success<T>) -> Flowable<Success<T>>
                                   = upstream::map
val mapped:   Flowable<Success<T>> = map(mapper)
val loading:  Loading              = Loading()
val startWith:
    (Success<T>) -> Flowable<Success<T>>
                                   = mapped::startWith

startWith(loading)  // type mismatch
```

The more specific `Success<T>` type was already inferred earlier, and Kotlin does not backtrack to find the more general `StateModel` type. To force that to happen, you can manually state the types, for example

```
// be explicit about the general type of the mapper
upstream.map { data -> Success(data) as StateModel }.startWith(Loading())

// be explicit about the generic type R = StateModel
upstream.map<StateModel> { data -> Success(data) }.startWith(Loading())
```

---

Incidentally, you're currently losing `<T>` in `StateModel`. I would suggest changing the base class to include the type parameter.

```
sealed class StateModel<out T: Any>
object Loading : StateModel<Nothing>()
data class Success<T: Any>(val data: T) : StateModel<T>()
data class MyError(val message: String) : StateModel<Nothing>()
```

This will let you write, for example,

```
val <T: Any> StateModel<T>.data: T?
    get() = when (this) {
        is Success -> data
        else -> null
    }
```

Comment: Thanks your detail explanation.